# How to suppress (or fix) Intellij object function call warnings of objects that were declared in constructors

Tags: php, mysql, intellij-idea, pdo

I am using php and sql in Intellij, and I have about 30 warnings mostly pertaining to my functions that correspond to PDO object calls not being found. I do not understand why I am getting the warning: "Referenced method is not found in subject class".

It says that the method is not found in the subject class, which is understandable since the constructor needs to be called for the variable to be declared. It just seems that the intellij interpreter does not realize that the constructor declares this.

I do have an sql dialect set up and working, and a data source. These eliminated several warnings.

For example:

```
public $conn;

function __construct(){

    try {
        global $conn;
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        //echo "Test";

    }
}

function project_load(){
    global $conn;
    try {
        $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `FROM projects");
    }
}
```

For example the prepare statement is highlighted with the warning. This code works perfectly, but the warnings are annoying and may cause issues in the future. Should I go and manually suppress them or are they solvable? Is this an issue with how intellij settings are set or is there an actual way to code this to avoid these warnings? Is it possible that this is a language issue? I believe Java handles this far better since it is natively object oriented.

Comment: Did you try alt-enter or right click and suppress the warning?

Comment: What I was wondering was if there was a way to resolve the warning without suppression. Suppressing the warning was more of a last resort. I don't get warnings like this in Java so I thought that I was doing something wrong with my php.

Comment: Are you using intellij or phpstorm? Sorry but i have little knowledge of php, and i suspect you are right, that the inspections may not be to the same level as the java inspections are.

Comment: Intellij. I saw in another post that you literally just shut off a setting in inspection, however I would really like to be able to resolve the warning with better code if that is possible. I do think that this could be one of the reasons why some devs hate php.